# creating multiple images in one packer build command

Tags: packer, hashicorp, packer-builder

I'm using the command `packer build -only=*image1*,*image2*`

I have few *'build.pkr.hcl'* files with the following code:

```
build {

  source "source.azure-arm.windows" {
      name               = "image1-2016"
  }
  source "source.azure-arm.windows" {
      name               = "image1-2019"
  }

  source "source.azure-arm.windows" {
      name               = "image2-2016"
  }
  source "source.azure-arm.windows" {
      name               = "image2-2019"
  }

}
```

The issue is that only two images (image2-2016 & image2-2019) are built instead of four.

What do I miss?